# Updating tumblr api call to use the new version of their api

Tags: php, api, tumblr

My site used to automatically submit all user generated artwork to a tumblr blog using the code below. Tumblr have now changed their api to v2. Any help on updating the block of code as below to work with the new version of the api would be greatly received. Thanks.

```
//submit to tumblr blog
// Authorization info
$tumblr_email    = 'XXXXXXXXXX@drawaplanet.com';
$tumblr_password = 'XXXXXXXXXXX';

$post_type  = 'photo';
$caption = $userCaption;
$post_title = '';
$post_body  = '';
$source = 'http://www.drawaplanet.com/drawaplanet/gallery/' . $filename;
$click_through_url = 'http://www.drawaplanet.com/planet.php?s=' . $source; 

// Prepare POST request
$request_data = http_build_query(
array(
    'email'     => $tumblr_email,
    'password'  => $tumblr_password,
    'type'      => $post_type,
    'caption'   => $caption,
    'title'     => $post_title,
    'body'      => $post_body,
    'source'    => $source,
    'click-through-url' => $click_through_url,
    'generator' => 'DRAWAPLANET'
)
);

// Send the POST request (with cURL)
$c = curl_init('http://www.tumblr.com/api/write');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_data);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($c);
$status = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($c);
```

Comment: If a php developer wants to write the code for me I'd be willing to pay $50 by paypal for some working code which uses tumblrs api v2 for this.

Comment: I had done something similar, using the v2, but I had some problems with large photoset (small ones and other kind of posts are quite ok), take a look here and if you want to contribute, you are welcome:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36747697/oauth-signature-creation-issue-with-php